# How to bring the menu to the center

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to bring the menu to the center, but I still do not know how to do it.
O yeah, I use actions and TextButton to put it

I have tried to put Center widget, and I think I use the wrong method.
This is the code, as you can see I put the button on actions = [].

```
    actions: [
            // Dashboard
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Dashboard'),
            ),

            // Home
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Home'),
            ),

            // History
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('History'),
            ),

            // Area
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Area'),
            ),

            // Users
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Users'),
            ),

            // Excavator
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Excavator'),
            ),

            // Notification button
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.notifications_none,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),

            // Person profil button
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: Wait me a moment

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your actions list widget with Row and assign mainAxisAlignment to center. And it will work.

```
actions: [
               Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children : [
    // Dashboard
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Dashboard'),
                ),

            // Home
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Home'),
            ),

            // History
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('History'),
            ),

            // Area
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Area'),
            ),

            // Users
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Users'),
            ),

            // Excavator
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Excavator'),
            ),

            // Notification button
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.notifications_none,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),

            // Person profil button
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
]
) 
          ],
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to say, it changes nothing

Comment: but I have add the picture of layout when I inspect it with Devtools, maybe you want to look at it

Comment: If its appBar then wrap whole appBar with Row and Wrap drawer with Align widget and make Drawer to the center left.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Row` widget in the `title` property of `AppBar`

[image]

```
AppBar(
    title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Dashboard', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),

      // Home
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Home', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),

      // History
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('History', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),

      // Area
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Area', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),

      // Users
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Users', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),

      // Excavator
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Excavator', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  actions: [
    // Notification button
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.notifications_none,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),

    // Person profil button
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.person_outline_rounded,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```